# How can I provide a value in minutes to setAnimationDuration?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

I think a value of 1.0 represents one second, but I'm not very sure with that. Is that a hexadecimal system? What would you provide to give exactly one minute for duration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a time interval, in seconds.  One minute would be 60.0.

Comment: All time intervals in Cocoa APIs (CoreFoundation / Foundation / UIKit / AppKit / etc.) are in units of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

This is in the included documentation you can find on Apple's site or contextually within Xcode

From the documentation [setAnimationDuration:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CATransaction/setAnimationDuration:)

> Sets the animation duration used by all
>   animations within this transaction
>   group.
>
> - (void)setAnimationDuration:(CFTimeInterval)duration
>
> Parameters duration An interval of
>   time used as the duration.

and [CFTimeInterval](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTimeUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CFTimeInterval)

> CFTimeInterval
>   Type used to represent elapsed time in seconds.

Comment: I was confused by that CFTimeInterval. So this thing is just nothing more than a double value?